# PHP can't find form element using Post

Tags: php, forms, encryption

I have 2 PHP files, `login.php` and `register.php`
I'm using `sha512` encryption and using the login mechanism from the [following site](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)
Some of the registration code appears there, but I created the registration form and changed the written registration form the site to be `process_registration'

In `login.php` , the form is sent using : `onclick="formhash(this.form,this.form.password);"`
Here is the `formhash()`: (from `forms.js`)

```php
function formhash(form, password) {
// Create a new element input, this will be out hashed password field.
var p = document.createElement("input");
// Add the new element to our form.
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
// Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
password.value = "";
// Finally submit the form.
form.submit();
}
```

So in order the registration and the login to have the same encryption process, the registration form should use this method as well, but when i get to `process_registration.php` with my form (and it gets there, with all the correct parameters) the `p` var doesn't exist in the `POST` although it exists in the `login.php` which is the exact same form and fields, except that the `login` uses `process_login.php` as its action and `register.php` uses `process_registration.php` as its action.

Here is the registration file form:

```php
<script type="text/javascript" src="sha512.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="forms.js"></script>


<form action="process_registration.php" method="post" name="register_form">
Username : <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
Name : <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br />
<input type="button" value="Register" onclick="formhash(this.form,this.form.password);" />
</form>
```

Comment: I would suggest using the onsubmit event of the form instead of the onclick event of the button so that you got every base covered. There also would be no need passing anything as the form will be responding on the `this` keyword inside the scope of that event handler. Besides this, your code seems ok and it may be that the problem is in the code you don't show us... there must be a difference somewhere.

Comment: I have to admit I cannot see what this would actually achieve from a security point of view. If I am a 'man-in-the-middle' I can still easily capture the user information and hashed password.

Comment: Please see this: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, to complete the creation and full definition of the new field before adding it to the DOM.

```
var p = document.createElement("input");
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
// Add the new element to our form.
form.appendChild(p);
```